# how to hide button when clicked from another view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am a beginner of xcode programming. I am trying to do an action, when i click button from A view, the button of B view will be hidden. I already know i can use `button.hidden = true;` for self view controller but I don't know how to control button from other view.

Thanks

```
@IBAction func TestBut(sender: UIButton) {
    setting.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: You want to hide button from another view controller ?

Comment: In Swift there is no need of semicolons `;`

Comment: Set hidden from instance of view B. <instance B>.<your button in view B>.hidden = true

Comment: @longpham what is an instance ?could you show me an example? sorry for my stupidity

Comment: @ray Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before, you create a custom view with button, button action and a protocol as:

```
protocol CustomViewDelegate {
    func buttonPressed (sender: AnyObject)
}

class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var delegate: CustomViewDelegate!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

   class func loadViewFromXib() -> CustomView {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView
    }

   @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate.buttonPressed(sender)
  }
}
```

In your ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {

var firstView: CustomView?
var secondView: CustomView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.firstView = CustomView.loadViewFromXib()
    self.secondView = CustomView.loadViewFromXib()

    firstView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    secondView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 100)

    firstView!.delegate = self
    secondView!.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(firstView!)
    self.view.addSubview(secondView!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (sender as! UIButton) == self.firstView!.button {
        self.secondView?.button.hidden = true
    }else {
        self.firstView?.button.hidden = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I want to hide CustomView button from UIViewController class ?

Comment: @ami rt I don't know what do you want here?

Comment: Hi, Actually i have a Custom view with  two button, and i want to hide it at runtime through UIViewController , So i don't get any exact thing to hide that button from UIViewcontroller class, Please do need full suggestion.

I got error that nil value. When i use below code:-
 `viewBottmNewOrder.btnNewOrder.isHidden = true` Basically i load nib file on Custom View class, and i just use Custom View class on UIView in Storyboard.

Comment: You should to check your ui element is not null first. Or Can you create a question & link me to. Thanks!

Comment: here is the link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931617/hide-custom-view-uibutton-from-uiviewcontroller-class

Answer (score 0):

the button has to be a property of the view( or view controller).
A call would look like this:

```
view.button.hidden = true
```

Comment: it shows 'testview.type' does not have a member named 'setting''
but thanks anyway

Comment: You have to define the Button as a global Variable or property of your current class or as a property of your view class to access it

Comment: how can i define a button as a  global Variable in swift? 
THANKS

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254