# Hide Custom View UIButton From UIViewController Class

Tags: swift, xib

Actually i have a Custom view with two button, and i want to hide it at runtime through UIViewController , So i don't get any exact thing to hide that button from UIViewcontroller class

Here is my CustomView class,

```
 import UIKit

class BottomButtonUIView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnNewOrder: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnChat: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    // MARK: init
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            setup()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomButtonUIView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? BottomButtonUIView {
            view.frame = bounds
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

            addSubview(view)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func btnOrderNowClick(_ sender: Any) {


        let VC1 = StoryBoardModel.orderDeatalStoryBord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewOrderViewController") as! NewOrderViewController
        VC1.isPush = false
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.

        let currentController = getCurrentVC.getCurrentViewController()
        currentController?.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func btnChatNowClick(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {

        if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            var currentController: UIViewController! = rootController
            while( currentController.presentedViewController != nil ) {
                currentController = currentController.presentedViewController
            }
            return currentController
        }
        return nil

    }

}
```

I set it to UIView in StoryBoard, and then I create outlet of that view,

```
 @IBOutlet weak var viewBottmNewOrder: BottomButtonUIView!
```

Now i want to hide `btnNewOrder` from UIViewcontroller class but when i use

```
 viewBottmNewOrder.btnNewOrder.isHidden = true it cause null exception, Please do need full answer.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't do like that. The `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will call a lot of times when the `BottomButtonUIView` created from xib. And your custom view will look like:

`[BottomButtonUIView [ BottomButtonUIView [btnNewOrder, btnChat]]]`.

So when you access to `btnNewOrder` like that:
`viewBottmNewOrder.btnNewOrder` it will null.

I think you should add your custom view in `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController'.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your gentle reply, actually i don't want to add it every time inside `viewDidload` in each and every class so thats why i did it.Kindly please tell me the best way to add CustomView to UIVIewcontroller View.

Comment: That's why Apple didn't suggest create a new custom view with xib. I think you should adding ui elements programmatically.

Comment: Here is the document for custom a control. You should to read it.
http://apple.co/2r0JYvx

Comment: Ok, you mean that i should load xib inside UIViewController UIView in ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: I meant you shouldn't add your custom view (with xib) in your xib/storyboard file of your `UIViewController`. You need to do it `viewDidLoad` of that vc.